# Meaning of notation in Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, bayesian, bayes-theorem

My lecture notes state Bayes' theorem, for data $\mathcal D$ of distribution parametrised by unknown parameters $\mathbf w$, as follows:

$$p(\mathbf w | \mathcal D)=\frac{p(\mathcal D | \mathbf w)p(\mathbf w)}{p(\mathcal D)}$$

After this, they refer to  $p(\mathcal D | \mathbf w)$ to as a "likelihood" and $p(\mathbf w)$ as the "prior *distribution*".

My confusion stems from the use of the notation $p(\bullet)$. Does this refer to a *probability*, a *probability density function* or to a *distribution* in the abstract sense (like we would write $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$? It seems to be used in various places to mean either. I attach below a screenshot from a wikipedia article highlighting a dual use as first a *distribution* and then a *probability*:

[image: contradiction in notation]

In the Bayes formula above, we have another example of potential mixing of the notations. In the continuous case, it appears to me that this formula implies the notation to be referring to a *probability density function*:

In the continuous case the likelihood **is** a probability density function. If $\mathcal D$ is continuously distributed, we define the likelihood $L(\mathbf w | \mathcal D):=f(\mathcal D | \mathbf w)$, where $f$ is the probability density function of $\mathcal D$ given parameters $\mathbf w$. We thus have $p(\mathcal D | \mathbf w)$ referring to a probability density function $f(\mathcal D | \mathbf w)$, and clearly then also $p(\mathbf w)$ and $p(\mathcal D)$ refer to PDFs too.

We thus have consistency in this case - though both uses of the wikipedia article contradict this; if $p(x|\theta)$ in the article refers to a PDF, it wouldn't make sense to say $x_i \sim p(x|\theta)$ right? That would be like saying $x \sim \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ instead of $x\sim N(0,1)$ - the former is the PDF of the standard normal, whilst the latter refers to the standard normal distribution itself. These are not the same thing, are they?

Bayes' theorem in the mixed discrete/continuous case is even more confusing - I find. If $\mathcal D$ is discrete, then the likelihood $p(\mathcal D | \mathbf w)$ is a probability (in the discrete case, $L(\theta | X)=\mathbb P(X|\theta)$). Should we have $\mathbf w$ continuous then $p(\mathbf w)$ is I believe still a PDF, and we are mixing probabilities and PDFs in the same formula - with the same notation being used for both. This could arise, for example, if we are counting the number of heads and tails (discrete) parametrised by some unknown probability continuously distributed in $[0,1]$.

Any clarification on all of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These are always probability *density* functions. Regarding if it makes sense to write $x\sim p(x|\theta)$ when $p$ is a PDF. Why not? Context makes clear what they mean. Notation is always just an abbreviation and rarely sacrosanct.

Comment: Also, the likelihood is the probability of having seen what we saw. In the discrete case this is easy to find, in the continuous case not so much so one assumes that one sees what we saw only up to a degree of approximation. Namely, the likelihood of $X$ having observed $t$ is $L(t) = P(X \in (t - \varepsilon, t + \varepsilon)),$ where $\varepsilon$ is assumed a universal constant and very small. Then, $L(t) = \int\limits_{t-\varepsilon}^{t+\varepsilon} f \approx 2\varepsilon f(t),$ where the approximation becomes better and better as $\varepsilon \downarrow 0.$ Often we simply say $L = f.$